# Execute groovy inside nextflow process using process inputs

Tags: regex, groovy, nextflow

I have a nextflow script with a channel for paired file inputs. I am trying to extract a substring from the file inputs to use as part of the shell call. I am trying to use Groovy's regex matching to extract the substring, but since it is based on an input value, I am having trouble executing the matching. An alternative would be to perform the regex in bash as part of the process shell call, but I am interested in figuring out how to manipulate inputs within a process anyways, as I feel it would be useful for other things too. How can I perform intermediate Groovy code with the process inputs prior to the shell call?

```
process alignment {
    input:
        val files
    output:
        stdout
    def matcher = "${files[1][0]}" =~ /.+\/bcl2fastq_out\/([^\/]+)\/.+/
    # this is the culprit, as if I hardcode the first string it works
    def project = matcher.findAll()[0][1]
    """
    echo ${project}
    """
}

workflow {
    files = Channel
            .fromFilePairs("${params.out_dir}/**{_R1,_R2}_00?.fastq.gz", checkIfExists:true, size: 2)
    alignment(files)
}
```

when I execute this, I get the error

`No such variable: files`

an example input string would look like `extractions/test/bcl2fastq_out/project1/example_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` where I'm trying to extract the `project1` substring

Answer (score 1):

As you've already discovered, you can declare variables in the [script](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) block, before the command string. For example:

```
process alignment {

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(fastq_files)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path(output_file)

    script:
    output_file = "${sample}.bam"

    """
    >&2 echo "Aligning ${sample}..."
    touch "${output_file}"
    """
}
```

Note that these are global (within the process scope) unless you define them using the `def` keyword. If you don't need these elsewhere in your process definition, like in your example, a local variable (using `def`) is usually preferable. If, however, you need to access these in your output declaration, for example, then they will need to be global.

Note that the [fromFilePairs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method emits a tuple, where the first element is a group key and the second element is a list of files. The problem with just using `val` to declare the inputs is that the *files* in the second element will not be localized to the working directory when your script is run. To fix this, you can just change your input definition to something like:

```
input:
tuple val(sample), path(fastq_files)
```

The problem with this approach, is that we're unable to extract the parent directory name from the localized filenames. So you will need to pass this in somehow. Usually, you could just get the parent name from the first file in the tuple, using:

```
params.input_dir = './path/to/files'
params.pattern = '**_R{1,2}_00?.fastq.gz'


process alignment {

    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(sample), val(project), path(fastq_files)

    """
    echo "${sample}: ${project}: ${fastq_files}"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( "${params.input_dir}/${params.pattern}" )
        .map { sample, reads ->
            def project = reads[0].parent.name

            tuple( sample, project, reads )
        }
        .set { reads }

    alignment( reads )
}
```

But since the glob pattern has an additional wildcard, i.e. `_00?`, you may not necessarily get the results you expect. For example:

```
$ mkdir -p path/to/files/project{1,2,3}
$ touch path/to/files/project1/sample1_R{1,2}_00{1,2,3,4}.fastq.gz
$ touch path/to/files/project2/sample2_R{1,2}_00{1,2,3,4}.fastq.gz
$ touch path/to/files/project3/sample3_R{1,2}_00{1,2,3,4}.fastq.gz
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [determined_roentgen] DSL2 - revision: f80ab33ac8
executor >  local (12)
[a8/9235cc] process > alignment (12) [100%] 12 of 12 ✔
sample2: project2: sample2_R1_001.fastq.gz sample2_R1_004.fastq.gz

sample1: project1: sample1_R1_003.fastq.gz sample1_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample1: project1: sample1_R1_004.fastq.gz sample1_R2_003.fastq.gz

sample3: project3: sample3_R1_001.fastq.gz sample3_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample1: project1: sample1_R1_001.fastq.gz sample1_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample1: project1: sample1_R1_002.fastq.gz sample1_R2_002.fastq.gz

sample2: project2: sample2_R1_002.fastq.gz sample2_R2_002.fastq.gz

sample2: project2: sample2_R2_001.fastq.gz sample2_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample2: project2: sample2_R1_003.fastq.gz sample2_R2_003.fastq.gz

sample3: project3: sample3_R2_002.fastq.gz sample3_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample3: project3: sample3_R1_003.fastq.gz sample3_R1_004.fastq.gz

sample3: project3: sample3_R1_002.fastq.gz sample3_R2_003.fastq.gz
```

Fortunately, we can supply a custom file pair grouping strategy using a closure. This uses the [readPrefix](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v22.04.0/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/Channel.groovy#L523-L585) helper function:

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( "${params.input_dir}/${params.pattern}" ) { file ->
            prefix = Channel.readPrefix(file, params.pattern)
            suffix = file.simpleName.tokenize('_').last()

            "${file.parent.name}/${prefix}_${suffix}"
        }
        .map { key, reads ->
            def (project, sample) = key.tokenize('/')

            tuple( sample, project, reads )
        }
        .set { reads }

    alignment( reads )
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.04.0
Launching `main.nf` [loving_cantor] DSL2 - revision: 5a76ac712f
executor >  local (12)
[f4/74edbc] process > alignment (12) [100%] 12 of 12 ✔
sample1_003: project1: sample1_R1_003.fastq.gz sample1_R2_003.fastq.gz

sample2_002: project2: sample2_R1_002.fastq.gz sample2_R2_002.fastq.gz

sample1_002: project1: sample1_R1_002.fastq.gz sample1_R2_002.fastq.gz

sample2_003: project2: sample2_R1_003.fastq.gz sample2_R2_003.fastq.gz

sample2_004: project2: sample2_R1_004.fastq.gz sample2_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample2_001: project2: sample2_R1_001.fastq.gz sample2_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample1_001: project1: sample1_R1_001.fastq.gz sample1_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample1_004: project1: sample1_R1_004.fastq.gz sample1_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample3_001: project3: sample3_R1_001.fastq.gz sample3_R2_001.fastq.gz

sample3_004: project3: sample3_R1_004.fastq.gz sample3_R2_004.fastq.gz

sample3_002: project3: sample3_R1_002.fastq.gz sample3_R2_002.fastq.gz

sample3_003: project3: sample3_R1_003.fastq.gz sample3_R2_003.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response, as well as simple examples and providing resources for my learning. My previous implementation of fromFilePairs seemed to be working even with non-localized paths. Is there an advantage to having them local? Or is it just better practice to avoid possible changes to files while the pipeline runs?

Comment: Nevermind, I am encountering issues with it now, thanks :)

Comment: @DerrikGratz The advantage is that your tasks can be self-contained and run independently of your execution environment. For example, if you use AWS Batch and have files in S3. If those files in S3 are not staged locally when your task is run, your tool will likely raise a file-not-found exception or similar (unless of course the tool has s3 support baked in...)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, if instead of just jumping into the shell script with the triple quotes, you can start specifying the process execution script with "script:" then run Groovy using the process inputs

```
process alignment {
    input:
        val files
    output:
        stdout
    script:
    test = (files[1][0] =~ '.+/test/([^/]+)/.+').findAll()[0][1]
    """
    echo $test
    """
```